# How to search for "any" with .where() in firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to have an "empty" where query (that searches for anything).

Having

`db.collection('skies').where('sky','==','blue')`

right now I have to do

```
if (searchForAny){
  db.collection('skies').otherStuff();
}
else {
  db.collection('skies').where('sky','==','blue').otherStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have an "empty" where query (that searches for anything)

Yes it is. To solve that, simply remove the call to:

```
.where('sky','==','blue')
```

When you are using the `where()` function, you tell Firstore to return only those documents where the `sky` property holds the value of `blue`. If you need all documents, use only a reference to the `skies` collection, not a query.

Comment: As you can see, that is what I already do. But it is really cumbersome to have two different searches, since this is a rather frequent scenario.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand you. I'm afraid you're not since you are calling `otherStuff()` (don't know it might be) and in the else part you are using for sure a query. And why do you say "it is really cumbersome to have two different searches"? If you don't need two, use a single one.